# Got weird noises with auxiliary jack while charging in the car

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-note

I'm using Galaxy Note. And I got this weird noise with auxiliary jack while charging in the car.
There is no noise while music is playing, and there is no noise if the charger is unplugged.
How do I solve it?

Comment: Just to verify, you have an audio cable running from the 3.5 mm out on the phone to the 3.5 mm aux input on the front panel of your stereo? Or is it some custom installation? What's your charger?

Comment: @Sammy: Yep, audio cable running from the 3.5 mm out on the phone to the 3.5 mm aux input on the front panel of my stereo. The charger is just a USB car charger that fits to the lighter plug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of Googling around, I found 2 possible solutions:

1. **Hardware** solution: [**Kensington Noise Reducing AUX Audio Cable**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0031U1ATQ) - haven't tried it myself. Yet some guys at [android central](http://forums.androidcentral.com/htc-evo-4g-lte/176437-weird-noises-aux-jack-car.html) report it worked for them.
2. **Software** solution: [**Aux Noise Filter**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msdevs.auxnoisereducer) app - Tried it on my Galaxy Note. Works like a charm.

Comment: Yeah man, grounding is a real bitch! Humming noise problems in audio are often caused by some grounding issue. The cause is not easy to locate or identify. There's ground from the charger coming in to the phone, and then there's ground coming out of the phone via the 3.5 mm audio plug and enters the car sound system via the aux in. They need to have the same potential. But a ground loop isolator can often solve the issue. But I didn't expect to see this problem with a smartphone. So much for being "smart".

Comment: That Kensington looks promising. It probably has a ground loop isolator built into it. I'm not sure how that app can solve this type of problem. I'd say it cuts off some low frequencies when no music is playing and no other audio service is running, like receiving a phone call. I mean there's not much more you can do, software-wise. This is a hardware problem. It's a way of sweeping the problem under the rug. I'm glad it worked out. But in the long run you might consider getting that special audio cable or get the grounding checked out.

Comment: @Sammy: Can this grounding issue cause damage to the battery?

Comment: No, it can't damage your battery. It can't damage anything, it just causes interference problems. You don't even know you got a problem until you try connecting some audio equipment. Audio equipment, especially in cars, is sensitive to interference. Humming is just one of these problems, and it's usually caused by improper or not optimal grounding situation (from audio point of view). A professional car audio installer should be able to work it out. Check out [ground loop (article)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_%28electricity%29).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem on my Galaxy S4 - whining noise from alternator (changing pitch with engine revs) plus random static. It only occurred when the charger was plugged in the USB port, and when no music was playing. I installed Aux Noise Filter and it worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Now, that **is** weird!

- Play some music or unplug the charger.
- Try a different cable.
- Try a different charger.

I won't tell you to change your car, your stereo, or your phone, as those are expensive. But you can always try it out in someone else's car, if that's an option. You have to narrow down the problem by using trial and error method.

Comment: Hi Sammy, thanks for the quick answer. I Tried both different chargers and cables. Didn't helped.
Playing music or unplugging the charger are not an option sometimes (when GPS is running for example).

Comment: Playing music with the volume set to zero maybe? Weird work-around, but better than nothing until you have a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Tried changing the charger and audio cable. Only buying a ground loop isolator worked. The PAC SNI from Amazon solved my problem, and got high reviews too.

http://www.thoughtworthy.info/BlogPost/158/Android-Phone-Buzzes-in-Car-While-Charging-And-Listening-to-Music